# What to do with a closed question with a wrong top-voted answer?

Tags: support

I find an answer voted by 4 is wrong, and the question is closed. The mistake in the wrong answer is easy to make (found many similar false proofs, online). So I think it should be corrected to prevent the spread of the mistake. But it is closed.

[This page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980796/show-that-limsup-and-liminf-are-measurable-for-a-sequence-of-measurable-f).

Why the answer is wrong (Hope I did it right):

In fact, $\{\limsup f_n > x\}\subset \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{f_k > x\} \subset \{\limsup f_n \geq x\} $.

We don't have $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{f_k > x\} \subset \{\limsup f_n > x\} $ because consider $a \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{f_k > x\}  $, it could happen that $f_k(a) = \frac{1}{k} + x$, then $\limsup f_n (a) = x$.

In fact, $\{\limsup f_n \leq x\} = \cap_{m=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \cap_{k=n}^{\infty}\{f_k < x + \frac{1}{m}\} $. The last "$<$" can be replaced with "$\leq$".

Comment: "closed" means you can't post a new answer, but (if you have enough points) you can still post a comment explaining what you think is wrong. Or maybe someone reading this, who has enough points, and is interested in the question, willl go and do it.

Comment: 1. You are right that the accepted answer is incorrect and that it needs the usual modification. 2. The question being closed for lack of context, your energy might be more fruitfully spent on correcting **other wrong pages** on the same subject (I am sure there are tons on them, the subtlety of the notions of limsup and liminf, for real valued or set valued sequences alike, being notoriously difficult to grasp for beginners).

Answer (score 4):

Closed questions can be deleted if there is not sufficient value in keeping them, such as good answers or the question in itself having some value even though it fails to be appropriate for the site.

In the particular case here, the question post is poor, and the only answer is incorrect while otherwise being rather standard.

Thus in this case the best course of action in my opinion is just to delete the post. You cannot do this yourself due to lack of points, but you can mention the post in the chat-room [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude).

This generally seems to be a good course of action in cases of doubt or if one cannot take an action oneself for lack of points.